# JavaScript Regex Ternary string

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs, grunt-usemin

I'm using grunt usemin and filerev to versioned static assets along with uglify.

Things were working well for angular HTML template replacement in JS files until we ran into a case with if/else operators

```
if($scope.isPdf){
    $scope.templateUrl = '/views/results/breakdown-detailed.html';
} else {
    $scope.templateUrl = '/views/results/breakdown.html';
}
```

converting things to a single line ternary operator after uglify

```
$scope.templateUrl=$scope.isPdf?"/views/results/breakdown-detailed.html":"/views/results/breakdown.html"}}
```

Now the regex to target template strings for replacement no long capture all the html cases

```
/templateUrl\s?[:=]\s?['"]([^"']+)["']/gm
```

Would anyone have a regex that would cover the ternary case of both values?

If it could also cover the original case in a single regex that would be great.

$scope.templateUrl=$scope.isPdf?"/views/results/breakdown-detailed.html":"/views/results/breakdown.html"}}

```
if($scope.isPdf){
    $scope.templateUrl = '/views/results/breakdown-detailed.html';
} else {
    $scope.templateUrl = '/views/results/breakdown.html';
}
```

I'll throw the test in regexr to try it out.

Comment: I could see parsing a single stand alone construct, but it won't really work when its embedded within scoped language intrinsics. For that you have to parse the language.

Answer (score 0):

Use the regex of the form

```
templateUrl(([^?]*)\?([^:]*):([^;]*)|(\s*=\s*)[^;]*)
```

which would capture anything followed by a `templateUrl`

For example see http://regex101.com/r/hD4wU7/1 on how the regex matches.

**Explanation**

- `templateUrl` matches `templateUrl`
- `([^?]*)\?([^:]*):([^;]*)` matches the ternary operator

  - `([^?]*)\?` matches anything other than `?` followed by question mark
  - `([^:]*):` matches anything other than `:` followed by `:`
  - `([^;]*)` matches anything other than `;`
- `(\s*=\s*)[^;]*)` matches the `if` case.

  - `(\s*=\s*)` matches `=`
  - `[^;]*)` matches anything other than `;`

Comment: apologies if my question was misleading. The problem I'm having is that my regex was working fine for matching any lines with `$scope.templateUrl = 'filename'`. When uglifyJS converted the if/else to the ternary operator, my regex no longer was able to pick up the templateUrls of the ternary operator values. If you have a regex to match both/either ternary values, that would be great. Thanks for helping!